# Tensorflow 2 model runs with single output but fails with multiple. Can not squeeze dim[2], expected a dimension of 1, got 3

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, tf.keras, multipleoutputs

Model runs fine when I try with either one of the output/loss combinations but fails when I try to do both. So if I simply don't include one of the the outputs in the model definition and also remove the extra loss, it works fine.

```
def prepare_dataset(ds, shuffle = False):
  # ds = ds.cache()
  if shuffle:
    ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=500)
  ds = ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
  ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
  return ds

...model definition dataset fetching
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, [output_sp, output_norms])

train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train_file, y_train_1, y_train_2))
train_ds = train_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

#Here I check the first element and all parts of it have the right shape

model.compile(
  optimizer='adam',
  # loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquare(),
  loss= (tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError(), tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()), loss_weights=[.8, 1])


train_ds = prepare_dataset(train_ds, shuffle=True)
model.fit(
  augmented,
  # validation_data = val_ds,
  epochs=1,
  batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
  callbacks=[cp_callback]
)
```

[image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/scandy/Developer/RouxNN/models/normals_and_sp_transfer.py", line 245, in <module>
    model.fit(   File "/home/scandy/miniconda3/envs/tf-rouxnn/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1100, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)   File "/home/scandy/miniconda3/envs/tf-rouxnn/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 828, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)   File "/home/scandy/miniconda3/envs/tf-rouxnn/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 888, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)   File "/home/scandy/miniconda3/envs/tf-rouxnn/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2942, in __call__
    return graph_function._call_flat(   File "/home/scandy/miniconda3/envs/tf-rouxnn/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1918, in _call_flat
    return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(   File "/home/scandy/miniconda3/envs/tf-rouxnn/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 555, in call
    outputs = execute.execute(   File "/home/scandy/miniconda3/envs/tf-rouxnn/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 59, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name, tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.   (0) Invalid argument:  Can not squeeze dim[2], expected a dimension of 1, got 3
         [[{{node mean_absolute_error/weighted_loss/cond/else/_66/mean_absolute_error/weighted_loss/cond/cond/then/_387/mean_absolute_error/weighted_loss/cond/cond/Squeeze}}]]
         [[mean_squared_error/cond/then/_74/mean_squared_error/cond/cond/pivot_t/_400/_117]] (1) Invalid argument:  Can not squeeze dim[2], expected a dimension of 1, got 3
         [[{{node mean_absolute_error/weighted_loss/cond/else/_66/mean_absolute_error/weighted_loss/cond/cond/then/_387/mean_absolute_error/weighted_loss/cond/cond/Squeeze}}]]
```

Comment: Which line raises this error? And please attach error message to your question body. And try to provide your model definition, if you think it's related to multi output model definition.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it running by splitting up and then rejoining the data.

So I replaced this

```
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train_file, y_train_1, y_train_2))
train_ds = prepare_dataset(train_ds, shuffle=True)
```

with with this

```
train_ds_in = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train_file))
train_ds_out = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((y_train_1, y_train_2))

data_set = tf.data.Dataset.zip( (train_ds_in , train_ds_out) )
data_set = prepare_dataset(data_set)
```